# Javascript - DropzoneJS, Error message blocks link to remove file

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropzone.js

I set accpetedFile to only csv files and removable link to true, so there's a link to remove the file under the thumbnail.
When an user uploads a file that is not a csv, the error message that shows up, saying "You can't upload file of this kind" when the user hovers over the file thumbnail covers the removable link.

It seems like the "hover zone" covers more than the thumbnail, including the removable link.
What should I config in dropzone.js in order to make the "hover zone" smaller, so the user can click on the link to remove the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. Look for .dropzone .dz-preview .dz-error-message in the css file and change accordingly.